# Como faço para o minhas imagens preencher toda tela em css

Tags: css

Não estou conseguindo preencher a tela toda no css com minhas imagens.

```
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
*{
    list-style:none;

} /* Fazendo reset */
a{
    text-decoration:none;
} /* Links sem efeitos */

/* Carecteristicas de tudo que esta dentro da Div e com Link */
#content ul li a{
    position:relative;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Efeitos do texto */
#content ul li a p{
    color:#ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
}
/* Efeito do fundo preto do texto */ 
#content ul li:hover p{
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transition:all 0.8s ease;
    opacity:1;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0px;
}
p{
    font:normal 16px Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h5{
    top: 30px;
}

#content{
    width: calc(100%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vários imagens? utilize jquery + css é melhor para aleatória e imagens diferentes, se for css é não tem automação e apenas a figura sequência.

Comment: Não tá faltando  `body{padding:0;margin:0}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já citei antes https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/144303/3635 você pode usar `display: flex` e se precisar rodar em navegadores antigos use `display: table`

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container > .row {
    flex: 1; /*faz prencher*/
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fc0;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.container > .row > .item {
    flex: 1; /*faz prencher*/
    width: 25%;
}

.container > .row > .item > a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container > .row > .item > a img {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Usando `display: table` pra navegadores mais antigos (PS.: ainda não consegui fazer o ajuste da largura que ultrapassa o 100%, mas estou tentando corrigir e já edito novamente):

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
    display: table;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container > .row {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

.container > .row > .item {
    background: #fc0;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
}

.container > .row > .item > a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container > .row > .item > a img {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM5Wu.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note que eu usei:

```
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
```

Isto faz as imagens preencherem o conteudo, mas se quiser um preenchimento a partir do centro, terá que remover as imagens e usar background, exemplo:

```
.container > .row > .item > a {
    background: center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

E o html assim:

```
        <div class="item">
             <a href="#" style="background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YjCm.png)"></a>
        </div>
```

> **Nota:** esta é uma daquelas raras situações que pode ser util usar o atributo style